# Knockout.js - set insertMessages to false for only one viewmodel property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Using Knockout.js, is it possible to set the insertMessages to false for one and only one view model property, instead of using `ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: false });`, which I believe sets it to false for the entire view model?

Ex.

```
reasonDetails.extend({
        required: {
            message: 'Please make at least one selection',
            onlyIf: function () {
                return reason() != 3;
            },
            insertMessages: false
        }
    });
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Validation options can be specified in the databinding of the control. I am not aware of a way to specify this in the viewmodel itself.

In this example, turn on insertMessages for the page but disable for a given control.
http://jsfiddle.net/zrp4w8ks/

```
First Name: <input type="text" data-bind="validationOptions: {insertMessages: false}, value: firstName" /><br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" /><br/>
```